# Why onCharacteristicWrite() comes later than onCharacteristicChanged() in BLE communication

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to exchange some data between android and other arm device via BLE, and large data was splitted into small fragments since the limitation of MTU. For robustness, one frame CAN ONLY be sended(by `writeCharacteristic`) when its previous frame has been confirmed(by `onCharacteristicWrite`). now here comes the issues: when android device finished sending the last frame and then received data from peer device(by `onCharacteristicChanged`), it seams `onCharacteristicWrite` comes later than `onCharacteristicChanged`(at least log says that) and here is my code.

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        stateProcessError();                 // State = STATE_IDLE
        return;                              // Log.v("error occurs", "do something");
    }
    Log.v("didsend", "State:" + State);
    processEvent(sp_event.DATA_SEND_CFM, null);
}

@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    Log.v("didrecv", "State:" + State);
    Object msg = constructRxMsg(characteristic.getValue());
    processEvent(sp_event.DATA_RECV_CFM, msg);
}

private void stateSendAuthReq(sp_event event) {
    switch (event) {
        case DATA_IDLE: {
            SPTxMsgAuthReq msg = new SPTxMsgAuthReq(Mode);
            sendData(msg.getMsg());
        }
            break;
        case DATA_SEND_CFM:
            State = sp_state.STATE_RECV_AUTH_RES;
            Log.v("sendReq", "change State");
            break;
        default:
            Log.v("sendReq", "default");
            this.stateProcessError();
            break;
    }
}

private void stateRecvAuthRes(sp_event event, SPRxMsgAuthRes msg) {
    if (sp_event.DATA_RECV_CFM != event || null == msg) {
        this.stateProcessError();
        return;
    }
    if (MSG_TYPE_AUTH_RES != msg.getType() || STATUS_AUTH_READY != msg.getStatus()) {   
        Log.v("recvAuthRes", "incorrect param");
        this.stateProcessError();
        return;
    }                
    State = sp_state.STATE_RECV_NONCE;
}

private void processEvent(sp_event event, Object msg) {
    switch (State) {
        case STATE_IDLE:
            this.stateSendAuthReq(event)
            break;
        case STATE_RECV_AUTH_RES:
            this.stateRecvAuthRes(event, (SPRxMsgAuthRes) msg);
            break;
        ......
    }
}
```

Log shows the issue as this:

```
06-16 17:32:46.521 10300-10412/alps.ble.bt V/send: data:[-32, 3, 3, 1, 0]
06-16 17:32:46.621 10300-10406/alps.ble.bt V/didrecv: State:STATE_IDEL
06-16 17:32:46.621 10300-10406/alps.ble.bt V/constructRxMsg: data:[-31, 2, 3, 0]
06-16 17:32:46.621 10300-10406/alps.ble.bt V/error occurs: do something
06-16 17:32:46.621 10300-10406/alps.ble.bt V/didsend: State:STATE_IDLE
```

And next is the log when no error:

```
06-16 16:30:05.871 22401-22502/alps.ble.bt V/send: data:[-32, 3, 3, 1, 0]
06-16 16:30:05.911 22401-22471/alps.ble.bt D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnParamsChanged() - Device=68:68:28:40:12:8E interval=39 status=0
06-16 16:30:05.961 22401-22413/alps.ble.bt V/didsend: State:STATE_IDLE
06-16 16:30:05.961 22401-22413/alps.ble.bt V/didrecv: State:STATE_RECV_AUTH_RES
06-16 16:30:05.961 22401-22413/alps.ble.bt V/constructRxMsg: data:[-31, 2, 3, 0]
```

NOTE: code in peer device should be correct because everything was ok when I test on iOS instead of android.

I hope enough info has been provided and any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you really sure the peripheral sends the Write Response before the notification? You could verify this by using a BLE sniffer hardware or inspecting the HCI snoop log which you can enable in Android and then look at in Wireshark. And does the order really matter for you? Couldn't you rewrite your code so it works either way?

Comment: Yes, I checked this issue using frontline BPA600 and airlog showed order is correct so in my opinion maybe something was wrong in my using or setting. The state change in my code depends on these two functions, however you are right that I can rewrite it to avoid this issue. Anyway I will check it more and lastly thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

The issue still exists after so many tries and I have no choice but to avoid it like using buffer and flags, and I am willing to share it.

```
private boolean isSending = false;
private byte[] lastRecvData = null;

private void sendData(byte[] data) {
    Log.v("1", "Send data ...");
    mCharacteristic.setValue(data);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mCharacteristic)
    isSending = true;
}

@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
    isSending = false;
    if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        return;
    }
    Log.v("2", "Send data successfully");
    processEvent(sp_event.DATA_SEND_CFM, null);

    if (lastRecvData != null) {
        Object msg = constructRxMsg(lastRecvData);
        processEvent(sp_event.DATA_RECV_CFM, msg);
        lastRecvData = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (isSending) {
        lastRecvData = characteristic.getValue().clone();
    }else {
        Log.v("3", "Recv data");
        Object msg = constructRxMsg(characteristic.getValue());
        processEvent(sp_event.DATA_RECV_CFM, msg);
    }
}
```

For case reconnection, buffer and flag should be cleared.

```
public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        isSending = false;
        lastRecvData = null;
        ......
```

It will be much appreciated if anyone has better ideas or solutions to this issue, and finally thank you.